# Why does my credentials dialog freeze?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, freeze

Everytime I try to login into some network resource, the windows credentials screen freezes (for example, when connecting to a Terminal Server via RDP or trying to access network folders). Already saved credentials are still working (credentials that Windows had saved before the problem started).

I already disabled the smart card reader, but it didn't solve the problem. All Windows updates have been installed.

[image: Remote desktop screenshot]

Comment: That is the Windows Credential prompt, not something that is remote desktop specific. It is probably trying to "talk" to your Active Directory infrastructure (to which the machine is connected) for authentication and authorization and that is probably single-threaded and blocking on the server response (leading to the window to gray out). I don't think that there is any fix (except upgrading Windows or having a better connection to your AD infrastructure).

Comment: Exactly, the problem is not related only to the remote desktop connection, but occurs everytime that I try to connect to any network resource. I am not connected to a domain, I am dialing in via VPN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to uninstall de Dell Data Protection Security Tools. No more freezes since then.